# Count the number of times values appear within a range of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I output a list which counts and displays the number of times different values fit into a range?

Based on the below example, the output would be `x = [0, 3, 2, 1, 0]` as there are 3 Pro scores `(11, 24, 44)`, 2 Champion scores `(101, 888)`, and 1 King score `(1234)`.

```
- P1 = 11 
- P2 = 24
- P3 = 44
- P4 = 101
- P5 = 1234
- P6 = 888

totalsales = [11, 24, 44, 101, 1234, 888]
```

Here is ranking corresponding to the sales :

```
Sales___________________Ranking
0-10____________________Noob
11-100__________________Pro
101-1000________________Champion
1001-10000______________King
100001 - 200000__________Lord
```

Comment: Are ranges always exclusive? (i.e. no value can fall in two ranges at the same time) Also, are you working with integers only, or can you have floating point values?

Comment: Use a combination of Counter and dictionary

Answer (score 1):

This is one way, assuming your values are integers and ranges do not overlap.

```
from collections import Counter

# Ranges go to end + 1
score_ranges = [
    range(0, 11),         # Noob
    range(11, 101),       # Pro
    range(101, 1001),     # Champion
    range(1001, 10001),   # King
    range(10001, 200001)  # Lord
]
total_sales = [11, 24, 44, 101, 1234, 888]

# This counter counts how many values fall into each score range (by index).
# It works by taking the index of the first range containing each value (or -1 if none found).
c = Counter(next((i for i, r in enumerate(score_ranges) if s in r), -1) for s in total_sales)
# This converts the above counter into a list, taking the count for each index.
result = [c[i] for i in range(len(score_ranges))]
print(result)
# [0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule homework should not be posted on stackoverflow. As such, just a pointer on how to solve this, implementation is up to you.

Iterate over the `totalsales` list and check if each number is in `range(start,stop)`. Then for each matching check increment one per category in your result list (however using a dict to store the result might be more apt).

Comment: "As a general rule homework should not be posted on stackoverflow" I'm not so sure about that, see a more elaborate discussion on the topic at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822).

Comment: I agree, I should have been more specific. However, I would argue that this question falls into "Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation" - no effort has been undertaken by the original poster as such should not be posted.

Answer (score 0):

If your sales-to-ranking mapping always follows a logarithmic curve, the desired output can be calculated in linear time using `math.log10` with `collections.Counter`. Use an offset of 0.5 and the `abs` function to handle sales of 0 and 1:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import log10
counts = Counter(int(abs(log10(abs(s - .5)))) for s in totalsales)
[counts.get(i, 0) for i in range(5)]
```

This returns:

```
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter` and a `dict`:

```
from collections import Counter

totalsales = [11, 24, 44, 101, 1234, 888]

ranking = {
    0: 'noob',
    10: 'pro',
    100: 'champion',
    1000: 'king',
    10000: 'lord'
}

c = Counter()
for sale in totalsales:
    for k in sorted(ranking.keys(), reverse=True):
        if sale > k:
            c[ranking[k]] += 1
            break
```

Or as a two-liner (credits to @jdehesa for the idea):

```
thresholds = sorted(ranking.keys(), reverse=True)
c = Counter(next((ranking[t] for t in thresholds if s > t)) for s in totalsales)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution with no use of modules such as `numpy` or `collections`:

```
totalsales = [11, 24, 44, 101, 1234, 888]
bins = [10, 100, 1000, 10000, 20000]
output = [0]*len(bins)

for s in totalsales:
    slot = next(i for i, x in enumerate(bins) if s <= x)
    output[slot] += 1

output

>>> [0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have used the power of dataframe to store the values, then using bin and cut to group the values into the right categories. The extracting the value count into list. 
Let me know if it is okay.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
df = pd.DataFrame([11, 24, 44, 101, 1234, 888], columns=['P'])# Create dataframe

bins = [0, 10, 100, 1000, 10000,  200000]
labels = ['Noob','Pro', 'Champion', 'King', 'Lord']
df['range'] = pd.cut(df.P, bins, labels = labels)
df
```

outputs:

```
P   range
0   11  Pro
1   24  Pro
2   44  Pro
3   101 Champion
4   1234    King
5   888 Champion
```

Finally, to get the value count. Use:

```
my = df['range'].value_counts().sort_index()#this counts to the number of occurences
output=map(int,my.tolist())#We want the output to be integers
output
```

The result below:

```
[0, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```